# Is each Chebyshev Polynomial orthogonal with respect to the weight function?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

I computed the term $(T_{3})$ in the Chebyshev polynomials on Wolfram Alpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28%284x%5E3-3x%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2Cx%2C-1%2C1%29

After viewing this integral, I am wondering if each polynomial in the Chebyshev polynomial sequence, $T_{n}$, is orthogonal with respect to the weight function $(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}$.  If so, is that the reason why each product of two different Tchebychev polynomials are orthogonal to eachother with respect to this weight function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the $\sqrt{1-x^2}^{-1}.$ The "reason" behind it is that the sequence $\cos{nx},$ $n\ge 1$ is orthogonal on $[0,2\pi].$ More precisely, recall that $T_n(\cos x)=\cos{nx}$ and thus for $m\ne n,$ making change of variables in the integral below leads to
$$\int_{-1}^1T_n(x)T_m(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{ny}\cdot\cos{my}dy=0.$$

For more information see wikipedia page devoted to the Chebyshev polynomials: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality)

Comment: Thanks, leshik.  I see you have used two Chebyshev polynomials and the weight function.  In the integral I linked, there is only one Chebyshev polynomial and the weight function:  Would this integral bear any significance?

Comment: absolutely, the same holds for one integral. Just let $n=0$ in the above and recall that $T_0(x)=1.$